# XIBs with CollectionViewCell and UILongPressGesture error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My goal is to display a collection view cell that will open a new view controller(MovieDetailA) if you tap on it. Or open a popup menu (MovieDetailB) if you **long press** on it.

The way I have my project setup are with XIBS. My collection view is broken down like this:

> 1. MovieCollectionViewCell.swift  - (cell)
> 2. MovieCollectionViewController - (cell's functionality)
> 3. MovieMain.swift - (displays collection view).

I have the collection view working and MovieDetailA working when user taps the cell. I am using `NSNotifications` and `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` for the actions.

My issue is I can not figure out how to apply Notifications to a `UILongPressGesture`. I've posted the code for MovieMain.swift and have edited it to only focus on issue above.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self,         
    action:#selector(movieSelected(notification:)))
    gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    }

   override func addObservers() {
   super.addObservers()
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(movieSelected(notification:)), name: 
   NOTIF_MOVIE_SELECTED, object: nil) }

  @objc func movieSelected(notification: NSNotification) {
  guard let movie = notification.object as? Movie else {  -- I think error is coming from this line. 
        return
    } }
```

Once I run the app, I get the error below,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILongPressGestureRecognizer
>   object]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the method `movieSelected(notification:)` as the action of the long press

```
   let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self,         
     action:#selector(movieSelected(notification:)))
```

and in this line

```
   guard let movie = notification.object
```

you ask the `notification` which is of type `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for `object` property that for sure doesn't exist , hence the crash

that method works for this notification

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(movieSelected(notification:)), name:
```

To accomplish your goal you must add the long press to the cell in `awakeFromNib`

and in this method , post the notification

```
 @objc func movieSelected(notification: NSNotification) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(NOTIF_MOVIE_SELECTED), object:self)

  }
```

and according to the observer in the VC that contains the collectionView you will get the cell itself and ask it for it's current model to show in the popup